# Nodejs server- MEDIA12899: AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type in IE

Tags: node.js, internet-explorer, mime-types, mp4

I have a mp4 file that it could be played in chrome but not in IE. When I check IE it shows

> MEDIA12899: AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type.

error. There are many similar questions here but none of them point to nodejs server. apparently, when I am in the first page of the site where it has views rendering, images, css, js and mp4 I need to identify the mimetype of all such files in `get('\' (req,res)` middleware. But I have no idea how to do it to solve this problem in IE.

UPDATE:

I have noticed that in the first time when I reload the IE page I get access denied and after that always I get "MEDIA12899: AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type." error. 
The video that I use in the page is an external resource. I moved it in to my local and surprisingly it could be loaded by IE. After some research I found the problem is related to CORS.
I added the following middleware but still I could not load the external video resource via IE ...

```
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, SEARCH, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Content-Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Location, Lock-Token, If");
  res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","DAV, content-length, Allow");
  next();
});
```

Comment: To enable cross-origin access go to Tools->Internet Options->Security tab, click on “Custom Level” button. Find the Miscellaneous -> Access data sources across domains setting and select “Enable” option. Let us know your testing result. We will try to provide further suggestions.

Comment: Thanks but I want I handle this on my server side as I do not have access to clients browsers!

Comment: It can be possible that your above code solved the issue for CORS but now you also need to solve the mime type related issue. Are you still getting those 2 same errors?

Comment: Yes. The main issue is just CORS issue as if I just load the file locally it works. In node js I also used CORS module but it does not effect on IE

Comment: If you are sure that issue is regarding CORS than you can refer these links may help to solve the issue. https://www.codementor.io/nodejsappdeveloper/how-to-add-cors-functionality-to-your-nodejs-web-app-ed4eu7ltf or https://dzone.com/articles/cors-in-node